# How to check if two different strings from two different files are present in third file?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-multithreading

I want to check if two different strings which are from two different files are present in third file and if they are present then write that line to fourth file. The set of strings are IPv4 addresses. I am getting empty file even if the strings are present in both files. Also I want to implement multi-threading/multiprocessing to speed up the process if possible. Thank you so much for any suggestion/help in advance.

slave_list text file has entry as below:

```
hostA 192.168.15.32
hostB 192.168.15.33
hostC 192.168.15.37
```

static_ip_list text file has entry as below:

```
192.168.100.10
192.168.100.12
192.168.100.14
```

slave_logfile has entry as below:

```
1536043051.176  59320 192.168.100.10 TCP_MISS/200 21830 CONNECT www.google.com:443 - 192.168.15.32
```

Code:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import os
import string
import sys


slave_list = sys.argv[1]
static_ip_list = sys.argv[2]
append_log = open('/home/top10_domain_accessed/logs/append_logs.txt', 'a')
def file_path (slave_list):
  count = 1
  while(count <=30):
  Nth_days = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=count)
  date = Nth_days.strftime("%Y%m%d")
  yr_month = Nth_days.strftime("%Y/%m")
  file_name = 'local2' + '.' + date
  with open(slave_list) as file:
        for line in file:
            string = line.split()
            slave_name = string[0]
            slave_ip = string[1]
            log_path = "/LOGS/%s/%s" %(slave_name, yr_month)
            slave_logfile = os.path.join(log_path, file_name)
            if os.path.exists(slave_logfile):
               log_read = open(slave_logfile, 'r')
               for line in log_read:
                 if slave_ip in line:
                    with open(static_ip_list) as ip_list:
                       for static_ip in ip_list:
                          static_ip = static_ip.rstrip()
                          if static_ip in line:
                             append_log.write(line + '\n')
            else:
             pass

        count = count + 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
     file_path(slave_list)
```

Comment: You code is going to be very inefficient with 3 nested for loops having to look through the contents of each file N times. It also is harder to keep track of overlapping IP's (and making your code hard to follow). I would suggest storing the IP addresses of a file inside a set/hashmap which then you can reference to see if that IP is in the list or not.

Comment: @Karl, Thanks for your suggestion. Any code example for set/hashmap implementation would be great !

Comment: Your code is kind of hard to tell what exactly it is checking with all the loops. But you can initialize a set by doing `ip_set = set()`. If you have two sets of IP addresses and want to find if one IP from each set is located in a record for that log, why not just loop through the log files themselves as the master for loop and pull out the two IP addresses for that log? Then you do a lookup to see if each IP address is inside a set that you pre-process to fill in with the IP addresses you want to check for. If both are in the sets then wriete to your file.

Comment: @Karl, It sounds good concept but I have variable log files and the location and name of log files are determined by slave_list first column value. Not sure how to start with it. Is it good to loop through variable log files?

Comment: Yes so you pre-process the slave_list and get all the IP's into a set and the location of every log file into a list. And then pre-process the static_ip's into a set as well. Then you can go line by line for each log file, extract their IP's and compare it against your two pre-processed sets of IP's